# Export content of main panel to PDF file in Shiny

Tags: r, pdf, export, shiny

I have created a Shiny app involving a simple sidebar layout. The main panel contains four plots and a table which are created and rendered according to certain user-specified parameters. I am trying to add a "download button" so that the user can download (and/or print) all these plots and tables displayed on the main panel. So far I have found this for ui.R

```
conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.returnpdf == true",
    strong("PDF size (inches):"),
    sliderInput(inputId="w", label = "width:", min=3, max=20, value=8, width=100, ticks=F),
    sliderInput(inputId="h", label = "height:", min=3, max=20, value=6, width=100, ticks=F),
    br(),
    downloadLink('pdflink')
  )
```

and this for server.R

```
plotInput <- reactive({
if(input$returnpdf){
  pdf("plot.pdf", width=as.numeric(input$w), height=as.numeric(input$h))
  plot(rnorm(sample(100:1000,1)))
  dev.off()
}
plot(rnorm(sample(100:1000,1)))
})

output$myplot <- renderPlot({ plotInput() })
output$pdflink <- downloadHandler(
 filename <- "myplot.pdf",
 content <- function(file) {
   file.copy("plot.pdf", file)
 }
)
```

but that does not quite work. How can I modify such code so that R takes a "screenshot" of the whole current main panel and exports it to a PDF file?

Comment: Were you able to get a solution for this?